# Preparing for an introduction meeting

Tags: meetings, first-job

**History:**

When I was between the second and the third year on the university I looked for some company to work or do an internship. I got in touch with companies of my interest, which although related to my degree it doesn't provide a good formation to that field. I was kindly rejected in a interview with a start-up.

Two years later (this summer) the same start-up posted a job position I applied for. I got again rejected but with a promise of a future meeting. At the end of the month I will have this meeting.

The reason of the meeting for me it is not clear. The first message stating about a meeting was "to talk." Now I have worded the reminding email as a meeting to see if I can collaborate.

I am confident about my skills, I already had experience abroad, I was almost a year abroad in an internship in related tasks.

**Question**

How should I prepare? What should I expect of the meeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not believe that you fit the needs of the position they advertised. However, they still wish to speak to you. It seems probable that they see another possible opening where you could be of use to them, and wish to sound out your capability and availability. This is therefore likely to be an exploratory meeting rather than another interview.

The key thing you need to do in this meeting is listen. They're currently entertaining the possibility that you're a good fit for some role you know nothing about. Until you know what the role is and whether you're interested in it, you have little useful to tell them.

It would also be advisable not to be too hasty to respond while in the meeting. You may feel differently about what they tell you after an hour or two of thought than you do in the heat of the moment. Instead, listen patiently and be courteous.